# AIX: remove the last symbols (CRLF) from a file

Tags: aix

There is a large file where the last symbols are `\r\n`. I need to remove them. It seems to be equivalent to removing the last line(?).
**UPD**: no, it's not: a file have only one line, which ends with `\r\n`.

I know two ways, but both don't work for AIX:

```
sed 's/\r\n$//' file # I don't why it doesn't work
head -c-2 # head doesn't work with negative numbers
```

Is there any solution for AIX? A lot of large files must be processed, so performance is important.

Comment: Program `split(1)` would be an option... Something like this: `export Fname=insertfilenamehere; Fsize="$(set -- `ls -l $Fname` ; echo $5)"; export NewSize=$(expr $Fsize - 2); split -b "$NewSize" -- "$Fname"; mv xaa ${Fname}_${NewSize}`

Comment: `dos2unix file` may be all you need. make a copy of your smallest problem file and test on that. With luck, it will load without issue or further messing around. Note that you can specify multiple files as arguments to one invocation of `dos2unix`. Good luck.

Comment: My last comment lost its formatting, next try: `export Fname=insertfilenamehere; Fsize="$(set -- $(ls -l $Fname); echo $5)"; export NewSize=$(expr $Fsize - 2); split -b "$NewSize" -- "$Fname"; mv xaa ${Fname}_${NewSize}`

Comment: Your `sed` command doesn't work, because the `\n` is not part of the string processed. Do you really want to remove that character?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you need to edit a file via a script in place, I use `ed` due to historical reasons.  For example:

```
ed - /tmp/foo.txt <<EOF
g/^$/d
w
q
EOF
```

`ed` is more than a bit cantankerous.  Note also that you did not really remove the empty lines at the bottom of the file but rather all of the empty lines.  With `ed` and some practice you can probably achieve deleting only the empty lines at the bottom of the file.  e.g. go to the bottom of the file, search up for a non-empty line, then move down a line and delete from that point to the end of the file.  `ed` command scripts act (pretty much) as you would expect.

Also, if they really do have \r\n, then those are not going to be considered empty lines but rather lines with a control-M (\r) in them.  You may need to adjust your pattern if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

My answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083912/3220113 to the duplicate question    should work here too. Another solution is using

```
awk ' (NR>1) { print s }
      {s=$0}
      END { printf("%s",substr($2, 1, length($2)-1) ) }
    ' inputfile
```